# markdown not using emmet

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, emmet

I have included the following in my vs-code user settings:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "vue-html": "html",
  "markdown": "html"
},
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
```

And would have expected to see **emmet** working for markdown files as an outcome but I get no suggestions and even if I explicitly press `⌃Space` it just comes up with "No Suggestions".

What else is needed to get emmet in Markdown files?

Comment: +1 for this, I could have sworn it was working previously and I'm not sure why just yet. Was hoping others with this issue had solved it.

Answer (score 42):

Okay, I got it working again. It looks like this is the default now in your user settings.

```
"emmet.excludeLanguages": [
    "markdown"
]
```

So it will trump the includeLanguages you've defined. Adding the following to my settings caused it to start working again.

```
"emmet.excludeLanguages": [],
"emmet.includeLanguages": {"markdown": "html"},
```

Comment: This is not working for me in VS Code 1.39.2. Has anything changed in the meantime?

Comment: Super thanks, this configuration works like a charm on vsCode v1.44.2 on linux

Answer (score 7):

Go to your user settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and enter "user settings"). Enter "emmet" there and click on "edit settings.json". Modify / add those lines:

```
"emmet.excludeLanguages": [],
"emmet.includeLanguages": {"markdown": "html"},
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding these in user settings to show suggestions for the new version (1.43.0) of VSCode

```
"[markdown]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

DerekR's answer is correct, but apparently there is a little more needed to get this working. Add these two lines to `settings.json`, per [this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/can-vs-code-emmet/):

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true
```

```
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never"
```

That got emmet working great in my Markdown files. Of course, there is the caveat of never showing an expanded abbreviation.

Comment: plus 1 for linking to the CSS tricks article. This showed me what I was missing